# How to use move semantics when popping an object from a queue?

Tags: c++, c++11

Please take a look at my code

```
class queue
{
        void pop(request & req)
        {
            mtx.lock();
            req = requests.front();
            requests.pop();
            mtx.unlock();
        }

    private:
        typedef std::queue<request> request_container;
        request_container requests;
        std::mutex mtx;
};
```

I am interested to use move semantics here `req = requests.front();`
Since I am going to pop the front object I don't further need it.
Hence, it is a perfect case to move the front object into `req`.
How would I do it?

Comment: `req = std::move(requests.front())`, but that assumes that `request` has properly defined `request& operator= (request&&)`. Otherwise, `move`ing is meaningless.

Comment: consider having `pop` return by value, otherwise the caller has to create a bogus default object and then move-assign the new value to it  . Offering both options might be the most flexible